# How to Vertically Center text in Awesome CV

Tags: vertical-alignment, awesome-cv

So I am using the Awesome CV template. Since the last entry in my 1st page doesn't fit at the bottom, it ends up at the top of the 2nd page. I have been been looking for a way to vertically center my whole page so instead of having a small gap at the top (over the header) and a big gap at the bottom, both gaps are the same.
[image]

I've seen a couple of ways to do it, including using the memoire class, but the awesome cv already has a document class...

The image isn't the 1st page, it's just for the demonstration and it's not exactly up to scale.

Here's resume.tex:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% Awesome CV LaTeX Template
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
% Template license:
% CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)
%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Configuration
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Themes: Awesome-CV
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{awesome-cv}

\usepackage[french,es-lcroman]{babel}
%%% Override a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\fontdir[fonts/]

%%% Configure a directory location for sections
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}

%%% Override color
% Awesome Colors: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange
%                 awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
%% Color for highlight
% Define your custom color if you don't like awesome colors
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-green}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8}
%% Colors for text
%\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{text}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{graytext}{HTML}{414141}
%\definecolor{lighttext}{HTML}{414141}

%%% Override a separator for social informations in header(default: ' | ')
%\headersocialsep[\quad\textbar\quad]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     3rd party packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Needed to divide into several files
\usepackage{import}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{name}{name}
\mobile{phonenumber}
%%% Social
\email{email}
\linkedin{email}

%\homepage{link}
%%% Optionals
\position{CPI{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}hi}
%\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {}%{\today}
  {name}%{name ~~~·~~~ Curriculum Vitae}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}

%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

%%% Import contents
%\import{\sectiondir}{presentation.tex}
%\import{\sectiondir}{english.tex}
\import{\sectiondir}{education.tex}
\vspace{-4mm}
\import{\sectiondir}{experienceIngenierie.tex}
%\import{\sectiondir}{experienceTravail.tex}
\vspace{-2.5mm}
\import{\sectiondir}{competences.tex}
\vspace{-2.5mm}
\import{\sectiondir}{committees.tex}
\vspace{-2.5mm}
\import{\sectiondir}{projetsEtudes.tex}

\end{document}
```

Here's awesome-cv.cls:

```
%% Start of file `awesome-cv.cls'.
% Awesome CV Class File
%
% This class has been downloaded from:
% https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV
%
% Author:
% Claud D. Park <posquit0.bj@gmail.com>
% http://www.posquit0.com
%
% Notes:
% 1) This class file defines the structure and layout of the template file (cv.tex, resume.tex).
% 2) It has been written in such a way that under most circumstances you 
% should not need to edit it.
%
% Class license:
% LPPL v1.3c (http://www.latex-project.org/lppl)
%


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{awesome-cv}[2015/12/14 v1.3 Awesome Curriculum Vitae Class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Class options
%
% (need to be done before the external package loading, for example because
% we need \paperwidth, \paperheight and \@ptsize to be defined before loading
% geometry and fancyhdr)
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Options for draft or final
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
% Inherit options of article
\DeclareOption*{
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                3rd party packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Needed to make fixed length table
\RequirePackage{array}
% Needed to handle list environment
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
% Needed to handle text alignment
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
% Needed to configure page layout
\RequirePackage{geometry}
% Needed to make header & footer effeciently
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
% Needed to manage colors
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%ligne horizontale centrée
\RequirePackage{xhfill}
% Needed to use \ifxetex-\else-\fi statement
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}
% Needed to use \if-\then-\else statement
\RequirePackage{xifthen}
% Needed to use a toolbox of programming tools
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
% Needed to change line spacing in specific environment
\RequirePackage{setspace}
% Needed to manage fonts
\ifxetex
  \RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
  % To support LaTeX quoting style
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\else
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  % Replace by the encoding you are using
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
% Needed to manage math fonts
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
% Needed to use icons from font-awesome
% (https://github.com/posquit0/latex-fontawesome)
\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
% Needed to deal a paragraphs
\RequirePackage{parskip}
% Needed to deal hyperlink
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={},
  pdfauthor={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  colorlinks=false,
  allbordercolors=white
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for directory locations
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure a directory location for fonts(default: 'fonts/')
\newcommand*{\fontdir}[1][fonts/]{\def\@fontdir{#1}}
\fontdir


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for layout
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Page Layout
% Configure page margins with geometry
\geometry{left=2.0cm, top=1.3cm, right=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm, footskip=.5cm}

%% Header & Footer
% Set offset to each header and offset
\fancyhfoffset{0em}
% Remove head rule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
% Clear all header & footer fields
\fancyhf{}
% Enable if you want to make header or footer using fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for colors
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Gray-scale colors
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{5D5D5D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}
% Basic colors
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{C2E15F}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FDA333}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{D3A4F9}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FB4485}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{6CE0F1}
% Text colors
\definecolor{darktext}{HTML}{414141}
\colorlet{text}{darkgray}
\colorlet{graytext}{gray}
\colorlet{lighttext}{lightgray}
% Awesome colors
\definecolor{awesome-emerald}{HTML}{00A388}
\definecolor{awesome-skyblue}{HTML}{0395DE}
\definecolor{awesome-red}{HTML}{DC3522}
\definecolor{awesome-pink}{HTML}{EF4089}
\definecolor{awesome-orange}{HTML}{FF6138}
\definecolor{awesome-nephritis}{HTML}{27AE60}
\definecolor{awesome-concrete}{HTML}{95A5A6}
\definecolor{awesome-darknight}{HTML}{131A28}
\definecolor{awesome-navyblue}{HTML}{213e8f}
\definecolor{awesome-green}{HTML}{179128}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-navyblue}

% Awesome section color
\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\or%
        awesome\else%
        awesome\fi%
    } #1%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for fonts
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set font for header (default is Roboto)
\newfontfamily\headerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-SemiBold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
]{Montserrat}

\newfontfamily\headerfontlight[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Thin,
  ItalicFont=*-ThinItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Medium,
  BoldItalicFont=*-MediumItalic,
]{Montserrat}

% Set font for footer (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\footerfont[
  Path=\@fontdir,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold
]{Montserrat}

% Set font for body (default is Source Sans Pro)
\newfontfamily\subtitles[
 Path=\@fontdir,
 UprightFont=*-Regular,
 ItalicFont=*-Italic,
 BoldFont=*-Bold,
 BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic
]{Montserrat}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[
 Path=\@fontdir,
 UprightFont=*-Regular,
 ItalicFont=*-Italic,
 BoldFont=*-SemiBold,
 BoldItalicFont=*-SemiBoldItalic
]{EBGaramond}



%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Configuration for styles
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Configure styles for each CV elements
% For fundamental structures
\newcommand*{\headerfirstnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfontlight\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerlastnamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{32pt}{1em}\headerfont\bfseries\color{text} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7.6pt}{1em}\headerfont\scshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headeraddressstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\headerfont\itshape\color{lighttext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headersocialstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{6.8pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{text} #1}}
\newcommand*{\headerquotestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\itshape\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\footerstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\footerfont\scshape\color{lighttext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{16pt}{1em}\subtitles\bfseries\scshape\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
\newcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{12pt}{1em}\bodyfont\textcolor{text}{#1}}}

% For elements of entry
\newcommand*{\entrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\headerfont\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\entrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\headerfont\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\descriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{text} #1}}

% For elements of subentry, pas utilisé pour le moment
\newcommand*{\subentrytitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\mdseries\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrypositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrydatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subentrylocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{7pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}
\newcommand*{\subdescriptionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{8pt}{1em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{text} #1}}

% For elements of honor
\newcommand*{\honortitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honordatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorlocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}

% For elements of skill
\newcommand*{\skilltypestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\skillsetstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{text} #1}}

% For elements of the cover letter
\newcommand*{\paragraphstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{14pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{text}\@sectioncolor #1}}
\newcommand*{\recipientaddressstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\scshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\recipienttitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{11pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\lettertitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} \underline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\letterdatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\lettertextstyle}{\fontsize{10pt}{1.4em}\bodyfont\upshape\color{graytext}}
\newcommand*{\letternamestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\letterenclosurestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{10pt}{1em}\bodyfont\slshape\color{lighttext} #1}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for personal information
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define writer's name
% Usage: \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
% Usage: \firstname{<firstname>}
% Usage: \lastname{<lastname>}
% Usage: \familyname{<familyname>}
\newcommand*{\name}[2]{\def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}}
\newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\def\@familyname{\@lastname}

% Define writer's address
% Usage: \address{<address>}
\newcommand*{\address}[1]{\def\@address{#1}}

% Define writer's position
% Usage: \name{<position>}
\newcommand*{\position}[1]{\def\@position{#1}}

% Defines writer's mobile (optional)
% Usage: \mobile{<mobile number>}
\newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{#1}}

% Defines writer's email (optional)
% Usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}

% Defines writer's homepage (optional)
% Usage: \homepage{<url>}
\newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}

% Defines writer's github (optional)
% Usage: \github{<github-nick>}
\newcommand*{\github}[1]{\def\@github{#1}}

% Defines writer's linked-in (optional)
% Usage: \linkedin{<linked-in-nick>}
\newcommand*{\linkedin}[1]{\def\@linkedin{#1}}

% Defines writer's stackoverflow profile (optional)
% Usage: \stackoverflow{<so userid>}{<so username>}
%   e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sam-smith
%       would be \stackoverflow{123456}{sam-smith}
\newcommand*{\stackoverflow}[2]{\def\@stackoverflowid{#1}\def\@stackoverflowname{#2}}

% Defines writer's skype (optional)
% Usage: \skype{<skype account>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}

% Defines writer's twitter (optional)
% Usage: \twitter{<twitter handle>}
\newcommand*{\twitter}[1]{\def\@twitter{#1}}

% Defines writer's quote (optional)
% Usage: \quote{<quote>}
\renewcommand*{\quote}[1]{\def\@quote{#1}}

% Defines recipient's information (cover letter only)
% Usage: \recipient{<recipient name>}{<recipient address>}
% Usage: \recipientname{<recipient name>}
% Usage: \recipientaddress{<recipient address>}
\newcommand*{\recipient}[2]{\def\@recipientname{#1}\def\@recipientaddress{#2}}
\newcommand*{\recipientname}[1]{\def\@recipientname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\recipientaddress}[1]{\def\@recipientaddress{#1}}

% Defines the title for letter (cover letter only, optional)
% Usage: \lettertitle{<title>}
\newcommand*{\lettertitle}[1]{\def\@lettertitle{#1}}

% Defines the date for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letterdate{<date>}
\newcommand*{\letterdate}[1]{\def\@letterdate{#1}}

% Defines a message of opening for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letteropening{<message>}
\newcommand*{\letteropening}[1]{\def\@letteropening{#1}}

% Defines a message of closing for letter (cover letter only)
% Usage: \letterclosing{<message>}
\newcommand*{\letterclosing}[1]{\def\@letterclosing{#1}}

% Defines an enclosure for letter (cover letter only, optional)
% Usage: \letterenclosure[<enclosure name>]{<enclosure>}
\newcommand*{\letterenclname}[1][Enclosure]{\def\@letterenclname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\letterenclosure}[2][]{
  % if an optional argument is provided, use it to redefine \enclname
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\def\@letterenclname{#1}}
  \def\@letterenclosure{#2}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for extra
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define separator for social informations in header
% Usage: \headersocialsep{<separator>}
% Default: \quad\textbar\quad
\newcommand*{\headersocialsep}[1][\quad\textbar\quad]{\def\@headersocialsep{#1}}
\headersocialsep


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for utilities
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Use to align an element of tabular table
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% Use to draw horizontal line with specific tickness
\def\hrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
% Use to execute conditional statements by checking empty string
\newcommand*{\ifempty}[3]{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{#2}{#3}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for elements of CV structure
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define a header for CV
% Usage: \makecvheader
\newcommand*{\makecvheader}{
  \begin{center}
    \headerfirstnamestyle{
      \@firstname
    } 
    \enspace\headerlastnamestyle{
      \@lastname
    }
    \\
    \vspace{0.4mm}
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\}}
    \vspace{0.4mm}
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\}}
    \vspace{-0.5mm}
    \headersocialstyle{
      \newbool{isstart}
      \setbool{isstart}{true}
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}
        {}
        {
          \faMobile\ \;\@mobile
          \setbool{isstart}{false}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{mailto:\@email}{\;\;\faEnvelope\ \;\@email}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\ \@homepage}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithubSquare\ \@github}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\ \@stackoverflowname}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\;\;\faLinkedinSquare\ \;\@linkedin}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\ \@twitter}
        }
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}
        {}
        {
          \ifbool{isstart}
            {
              \setbool{istart}{false} 
            }
            {\@headersocialsep}
          \faSkype\ \@skype
        }
    } \\
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}
      {}
      {\vspace{6.0mm}\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{5.0mm}}
  \end{center}
}

% Define a footer for CV
% Usage: \makecvfooter{<left>}{<center>}{<right>}
\newcommand*{\makecvfooter}[3]{
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{
    \footerstyle{#1}
  }
  \fancyfoot[C]{
    \footerstyle{#2}
  }
  \fancyfoot[R]{
    \footerstyle{#3}
  } 
}

% Define a section for CV
% Usage: \cvsection{<section-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{
  \par\addvspace{1.5ex}
  \phantomsection{}
  \sectionstyle{#1}
  %\color{gray}\hrulefill{0.9pt}
  %\myrulefill{10em}
  %\rule[2pt]{1in}{2pt}\vspace{3mm}
  %\xfill{1pt}{3pt}
  \color{gray}\xrfill[4pt]{0.9pt}
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}
}

% Define a subsection for CV
% Usage: \cvsubsection{<subsection-title>}
\newcommand{\cvsubsection}[1]{
  \phantomsection{}
  \subsectionstyle{#1}
}

% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<title>}{<position>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
       {\entrytitlestyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#1} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#2} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Define an environment for cvsubentry
\newenvironment{cvsubentries}{
  \begin{center}
}{
  \end{center}
}
% Define a subentry of cv information
% Usage: \cvsubentry{<position>}{<title>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cvsubentry}[4]{
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \setlength\leftskip{0.2cm}
    \subentrytitlestyle{#2} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {\subentrydatestyle{#3}}{} 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
      {}
      {\subentrypositionstyle{#1} & \subentrydatestyle{#3} \\}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}
      {}
      {\multicolumn{2}{L{17.0cm}}{\subdescriptionstyle{#4}} \\}
  \end{tabular*}
}

% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{13.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3}
  \\
}

% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{15.2cm}}
}{
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} 
  \\
}

% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{
  \vspace{-4mm}
  \begin{justify}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
}{
  \end{itemize}
  \end{justify}
  \vspace{-2mm}
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                Commands for elements of Cover Letter
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Define an environment for cvletter
\newenvironment{cvletter}{
  \lettertextstyle
}{
}

% Define a paragraph for cvletter
% Usage: \cvparagraph{<paragraph-title>}
\newcommand{\cvparagraph}[1]{
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}
  \phantomsection{}
  \paragraphstyle{#1}
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{0.4ex}
}

% Define a title of the cover letter
% Usage: \makelettertitle
\newcommand*{\makelettertitle}{
  \vspace{8.4mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \recipienttitlestyle{\@recipientname} & \letterdatestyle{\@letterdate}
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{singlespace}
    \recipientaddressstyle{\@recipientaddress} \\\\
  \end{singlespace}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@lettertitle}}
    {}
    {\lettertitlestyle{\@lettertitle} \\}
  \lettertextstyle{\@letteropening} 
}

% Define a closing of the cover letter
% Usage: \makeletterclosing
\newcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \vspace{3.4mm}
  \lettertextstyle{\@letterclosing} \\\\
  \letternamestyle{\@firstname \@lastname}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@letterenclosure}}
    {\\}
    {
      \\\\\\
      \letterenclosurestyle{\@letterenclname:  \@letterenclosure} \\
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, Ely! You increase the chances of getting help considerably if you add the *code* of your document such that we see all your settings and can propose a suitable solution. Currently, your question contains too little information to help with reasonable effort.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm a beginner and I thought it was pretty straightforward because it's the awesome cv template!